# What's the purpose of SMA antenna connector grounding? Can I just use a copper antenna with no grounding?

Tags: antenna

I'm looking at a schematic which includes an SMA antenna connector.  I'm wondering why this connector needs grounding and whether a simple copper wire without grounding can be used instead

[image: Schematic]

Would I be able to use an internal antenna like this one, with no grounding?

[image]

Comment: Sure you can use it , but the antenna performance could be poorer without a ground which may reflect a 1/4 into 1/2 wave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every antenna feed point requires two nets. If it's an unbalanced feed, the second net is the ground return.

By connecting the ground to the SMA connector, the board designer gives you the flexibility to use different antenna implementations. You may have a cable and then a remote antenna, or you may have an antenna right at the connector.

If you have a monopole antenna, you need to have a reference ground, which could be implemented using the board's ground plane. If you're simply going to connect a monopole antenna right at the SMA connector (no cable), then you may be right and the ground connection on the SMA side may not be strictly necessary, since the board ground will be part of the antenna. However, I see no penalty in connecting the SMA ground even in this case. You may actually be saving yourself from some trouble: the antenna you're going to use may have been designed taking the length on the SMA ground into consideration, or there may be matching components connected to the ground inside the antenna.

Answer (score 0):

The radiation pattern and gain of an antenna depends not only on the “driven” element but also one the counterpose.  Without a connection on the coax shield connector, the circuit board, and/or possibly its ground and power supply connections (etc.), become the antenna counterpose.  This geometry may or may not provide the directivity and/or gain you require.

With a connection to the coax shield (or feedline pair), you can place the counterpose in a more optimal location, for instance the other “half” of a tuned dipole or Yagi-Uda, or a solid ground plane under a vertical monopole, etc., located at some more optimal location (high, away from shielding, etc.)

The return current from the counterpose will use that shield connection.